# DRY in C# code documentation on two interface variants

Tags: c#, documentation, dry, fluent-interface

I am currently rewriting a SDK to access a webservice.

Since the model for a database query consists of many classes (actually one class for each of about twenty possible filters), I decided to provide a fluent interface additonally.

So instead of

```
new Query(
 Age = new AgeFilter() { From = 18, To = 65 },
 Location = new PostalCodeFilter() { Zip = 12345, new RadiusDefinition() { ... } }
);
```

the user can now write:

```
Query.Create()
  .WithAge(18, 65)
  .WithLocation(12345, 50, "miles");
```

Now I found out that the traditional way has to be included as well (I cannot hide the actual objects as internal).

How can I avoid having to document both the parameters of the fluent interface and the fields of the data classes? The descriptions are the same. I thought about see/seealso but this wouldn't show up in Visual Studio's Code Assistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Sandcastle you can use the [`<inheritdoc />`](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/79897974-ffc9-4b84-91a5-e50c66a0221d.htm) tag just like this:

```
///<param name="from">
///<inheritdoc cref="AgeFilter.From" select="/summary/node()" />
///</param>
```

or

```
///<summary>
///<inheritdoc cref="QueryFilters.WithAge" select="/param[@name='from']/node()"/>
///</summary>
```

Comment: I don't know if our documentation process allows us to use SandCastle, but this is definitely what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. An xml-doc comment is applied to a very specific thing and isn't easily "shared". But, you can "link" between elements using the `<see>` tag. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx and see if it's of use to you.

Understand that DRY really applies mainly to code; writing the same line of code twice means that if a change to the logic inherent in that code has to be made, it has to be made twice. What you're trying to avoid repeating is markup, which while it can have the same inherent problem of having to make changes in multiple places, markup usually has fewer tools available to avoid restating similar things. If you look at other libraries which have multiple ways to accomplish a similar goal, you'll find that a lot of the documentation appears copy-pasted.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I know the see-tag and actually included it in my question, but SO didn't show it being inside HTML tag marks. Actually, I don't second your opinion. The reasons for DRY you mentioned apply to documentation as well. Our SDK is available in different languages. A change in documentation ideally should not make it neccesary to change different languages.